# Function not printing/catting a value i'm telling it to

Tags: r, function, web-scraping, rvest

I have a moderately large function and I want to `cat` it's progress as well as the URL of the webpage that iteration is attempting to scrape. However, my calls to `cat` are not doing anything.

When I strip the function right down (i.e. remove all of the substance from it, but still keep the `cat` call), it does print the progress though as expected.

##### This is the longer function I have:

```
## Set up sleeper function
sleep <- function(x){
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x)
  proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}

## Set up NULL objects to fill in function
episodes = NULL
l = NULL

## Set up function to get episodes
get_episodes <- function(.x, .y){
  tryCatch({
    if (.x == 34 & .y == 3){
       l = 'l'
    }
    new_episode <- try(read_html(paste0('http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/', .x, '-', .y, '.htm', l))) %>% 
      html_nodes("p") %>%
      html_text() %>% 
      tibble(value = .) %>% 
      mutate(value = str_squish(str_replace_all(
        value, "(\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)|\\s*\\[[^\\]]+\\])", ""))) %>% 
      filter(value != "") %>% 
      mutate(season_num = {{ .x }},
             episode_num = {{ .y }},
             airdate_orig = str_sub(.$value[1], -12),
             episode_name = str_sub(.$value[1], 1, regexpr(" O", .$value[1]) - 1)) %>% 
      slice(-1) %>% 
      mutate(value=str_split(value, "\\s(?=[A-Z]+:)")) %>% 
      unnest(value) %>% 
      mutate(character = str_extract(value, "^([A-Z]+)(?=:\\s)"),
             value = str_remove(value, "^([A-Z]+:\\s)"))
    return(episodes <- episodes %>% bind_rows(new_episode))
    cat(paste('\rseason = ', .x, '; episode = ', .y))
    cat(paste0('http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/', .x, '-', .y, '.htm', l))
    #sleep(.2)
  }, error=function(error){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(error), "\n")})
}

## Make all possible combinations of seasons X episodes
d1 <- crossing(season = c(27:38), 
               episode = c(1:13))

## Call function
episodes <- map2_dfr(
  .x = d1$season, 
  .y = d1$episode, 
  .f = get_episodes)
```

##### This is a much trimmed down version:

```
sleep <- function(x){
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x)
  proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}

fun_test <- function(.x, .y){
  tryCatch({
    l <- NULL
    if (.x == 34 & .y == 3){
      l = 'l'
    }
    print(paste0('http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/', .x, '-', .y, '.htm', l))
    print(paste('outer = ', .x, '; inner = ', .y))
    sleep(.5)
  }, error=function(error){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(error), "\n")})
}

## Make all possible combinations of seasons X episodes
d2 <- crossing(outer = c(27:38), 
               inner = c(1:13))

## Call function
test <- map2_dfr(
  .x = d2$outer, 
  .y = d2$inner, 
  .f = fun_test)
```

Additionally, you can see from the much trimmed down version (as it actually prints) that the url sometimes looks different from what i'd expect to see. In the function, i'm saying I want an htm suffix up until outer==34 and inner==3, and otherwise an html suffix; but what sometimes it's showing up as htmm, htmmm, or even htmlm. Does anyone know what's causing this? Are you others able to replicate it?

##### Edit:

I've included the `l <- NULL` statement inside the `fun_test` function but the problem with doing that is that I only get an html suffix for the URL on that specific iteration, outer==34 and episode==3, whereas what I want is an html suffix for that and any iteration after it until the function ends.

Comment: Define `l` inside your function, not outside, so put `l <- NULL` in the first line of `get_episode()` or `fun_test`.

Comment: What OS are you using? Maybe add `flush.console()` after the `cat()`

Comment: I'm not sure about the trimmed version but in your long version I only see cat statements *after* the call to return so I wouldn't expect those to ever get executed

Comment: `flush.console()` didn't make any difference, neither has putting `l <- NULL` inside either `get_episode()` or `fun_test`. Moving the `return` call further down so it is below the `cat` statements has solved the printing issue. Still getting some unexpected behaviour in terms of what's actually being printed though -- am about to edit post now

Comment: Using `if (paste0(.x,.y) >= 343){ l = 'l' }` seems to have gotten me someway towards what I want, but when `.y` ticks into two-digit numbers it reverts back to `l = NULL`. I don't understand this as i'd think that 3410, for example, or 3411 is `>= 343`

Comment: Ok, wrapping the `paste0()` in `as.numeric()` has done the trick! Thanks all